# How to make a bootable XP USB Disk with additional software?

Tags: windows, usb-storage, bootable-media

I know how to make a USB disk bootable but I want to know that how can I add additional software's like Microsoft Office, Adobe Reader, Notepad++, etc. with the installation of Windows setup?

Comment: I think nlite is the best tool for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/how-to-make-a-custom-windows-install-w-nlite) is the tutorial for you what you want. [Tutorial for nlite](http://www.winaddons.com/nlite-14-tutorial) will clear you more on this. [Integrate drivers](http://komku.blogspot.com/2007/11/integrate-driver-into-windows.html) is the very good link I found for this purpose. Hope this will help you. Best of luck.